# How to get the generic reference of an javascript inbuilt function

Tags: javascript

Mozila supports a method contains on string type which is nothing bu fancy indexOf but contains is not supported in chrome,what i want is ,in initialization i will set up a reference say '`x.myIndexOf`' so that when I call `x.myIndexOf("hey","niddle");` it will internally call the `indexOf` or `contains` depending on the browser.

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains ? Don't use it. Use `includes` instead. It's supported by all latest versions of Firefox and Chrome. Use then polyfill (from the same page) if you need support for other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ,

```
browser.setBrowserSpecificIndexOf=function()
{
    switch(MBTProperties.currentBrowser)
    {
    case "firefox":
        browser.indexOf=function()
        {
        var hayStack= arguments.callee.arguments[0];
        var niddle= arguments.callee.arguments[1];
        return hayStack.contains(niddle);
        };
    break;

    case "chrome":
        browser.indexOf=function()
        {
        var hayStack= arguments.callee.arguments[0];
        var niddle= arguments.callee.arguments[1];
        return hayStack.indexOf(niddle)==-1?false:true;
        };
        break;
    default:
        console.log("browser not supported ");
        result=false;
    }
};
```

`browser.setBrowserSpecificIndexOf()` this function is called only once after than depending on the browser the implementation of `indexOf` will invoke ,thanks ,now each time we dont have to check which browser it is working on .